# How to pass all the checked checkboxID to REST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am learning web development and I have created some checboxes. At present I have four checkbox. I want to send my "REST Service" all the checkboxesID which are checked by the user. Below is what I have attempted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id = "1" name="graphId" value="1">Graph1<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id = "2" name="graphId" value="2">Graph2<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id = "3" name="graphId" value="3">Graph3<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id = "4" name="graphId" value="4">Graph4<br> 
<input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!"/> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="Redirect" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
    $("#btnGetResponse").click(function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            // HARD CODED graphId=1 in the URL, I need it to be the checkboxId which are checked
            url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/CheckBox?graphId=1",
            data: '{}', // Need to get the checked checkboxes ID here
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) 
            {
               if (response == true) 
               {
                sessionStorage.setItem('uiResponse', true);
                window.location.href = "../backbonetest/dashboardUI.html";
               }
            },
            failure: function (response) 
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [**`jQuery.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) over [**`:checked`**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.

Pass `mapped` ids in `data` object.

```js
$("#btnGetResponse").click(function() {
  var ids = $('[name="graphId"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
  console.log(ids);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/CheckBox",
    data: {
      checked: ids
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == true) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('uiResponse', true);
        window.location.href = "../backbonetest/dashboardUI.html";
      }
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="graphId" value="1">Graph1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="graphId" value="2">Graph2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="graphId" value="3">Graph3
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="graphId" value="4">Graph4
  <br>
  <input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!" />
</form>
```

Comment: I just forgot that OP mentioned *"...which are checked..."*. Also, for some reason, when attempting to put your code in a fiddle, it does not work...

Comment: @Rayon :Since I am new to all this it will take time to incorporate your code into my code. I will try it now and will see if it works, if any doubt I will ask you. Thank you so much

Comment: Also @Rayon, I know it works but why are you only using `this` and not `$(this)`. I thought referencing all jQuery elements required the latter but it does not seem to work when I do i that way...

Comment: @wmash, `this` refers to `DOM` element not `jQuery-wrapped` object. To access id, no need to wrap it in `jQuery object`

Comment: @Rayon: Can you kindly help me here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015531/not-able-to-pass-correct-values-to-rest-from-checkbox

Comment: @wmash: Can you kindly help me here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015531/not-able-to-pass-correct-values-to-rest-from-checkbox